# Is There Any Way to Generate a Standard "Diff" Between Two Strings in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a site like Wikipedia or Google Docs, with an audit history of every change made to certain tables.  In other words, I want to set a trigger on table `foo`, so that every time the `bar` column changes, it adds a "diff" of the changes to a `foo_audits` table.

By "diff", I mean like the Linux tool `diff`, `git diff`, or any similar change tracker, where if the text "foo bar" was changed to "foo qux", the "diff" would be something like:

```
+ qux
- foo
```

(Except with the line/column numbers of the change added, using the standard diff format.)

Is there any way to generate such a diff in Postgresql?

P.S. A pure PostgreSQL solution would be nice, but I'd also be open to using another language.  For instance, Node JS has a [diff package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) that would do exactly what I want ... but I have no idea how to use it from inside a database trigger.

P.P.S. I found [this code](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/postgres-text-diff/blob/master/diff.sql), for what *looks like* a diff function ... but it's not a free-standing "give me two strings and I'll give you a diff" function; it instead INSERTs the diff into a table.  If anyone could help explain how I can extract the "diff" part of that script into its own function (sadly I'm not good at programming PostgreSQL), that would also solve things.

Basically I don't care *how* it works, I'm just looking for *any* solution that lets me diff inside the database ... and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're any good at Python, you might find [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) useful.

Comment: I'm fine with Python, but not with using Python within PostgreSQL (or rather, I'm fine with that too ... I just don't know how to do it).

Comment: You can compile PostgreSQL from source using the `--with-python`  option and/or you can install the `plpythonu` extension (`u` = untrusted). Never done it - will have to shortly, but if you're proficient in Python, might be worth a shot?